# Rename PDF Files with creation date in R

Tags: r, pdf, rename

I'm new in `R`. I'm trying to read a list of pdf from different folders and rename them with the creation date, but I can't.

```
files <- list.files(pattern = "pdf$", recursive = TRUE)
length(files)

creation_date <- file.info(files)$ctime

sapply(files, FUN = function(eachPath){

file.rename(from=eachPath, to=sub(pattern = "archivo", replacement = "(c(file.info(files)$ctime), eachPath))
})
```

Thanks in advance,

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of ways you can improve your script. First, I would make the path where you want to look in explicit and use the option `full.names = TRUE` to get the full path:

```
files <- list.files("C:/Users/Johannes Gruber/Desktop/test",
                    pattern = "pdf$", 
                    recursive = TRUE,
                    full.names = TRUE)
```

This is not always necessary but eliminates a source for potential errors.

Then you need to replace the `:` because it is not allowed in file names on some operating systems (like Windows). I also replace whitespace since this is a problem sometimes (not while creating files but maybe later).

```
creation_date <- file.info(files)$ctime
creation_date <- gsub("\\s|:", "_", creation_date)
# make new names from info
new_names <- paste0(dirname(files), "/archivo_", creation_date, ".pdf")
```

`file.rename` is actually fully vectorised so there is no need for the loop. This will work on many files at once and is extremely fast in my experience:

```
file.rename(from = files, to = new_names)
```